# how do i get an mobile app data through php

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get mobile app (android/ios) author name , total downloads, review, rating and other data about the app using php.
For example from this url

```
  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.threema.app
```

how i get the details of the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use html dom and simple class like this

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net